# Add Dynamically A LinkButton Inside Nested (Child) GridView

Tags: .net, gridview, controls

I am currently working as Junior .Net Developer, however, I am requested by my manager to develop a web page called staff deployment plan that will involve two GridViews, that is the Parent GridView and Child GridView. The Parent GridView will display two columns which are EmployeeNames and WorkingDays - the working days column is a heading of Child GridView and the child gridview displays columns as current working days for example: the month of November 2014 has 20 working days excluding weekends and public holidays in South Africa, so the columns for child gridview are like this: 3 Nov, 4 Nov, 6 Nov...etc

The problem that am experiencing now:

Is to add LinkButton for each column on the Child GridView and to create command event for each linkbutton inside a child gridview (remember this child gridview is inside a parent gridview) and the link button when is click it should display a popup window.

Any help in terms of how to accomplish this will be highly appreciated

Comment: Hi Riad:Here are front end code:

Comment: where is the code? any link?